# I am working on a school project and I want my h1 to move one row down so that my h1 is centerd again

Tags: html, css

So currently I am trying to make the `h1` move down a bit so that my top `nav` is free and that my `h1` is centered again. I have tried out some stuff but it didn't work. (My work is quite messy sorry in advance).

```css
header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
}

.header h1 {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 2;
}

.tobnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgb(29, 4, 255);
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #f80000;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-size: 130%;
}

table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid rgb(7, 7, 7);
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
}

th {
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<html>.

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initalscale=1.0">
  <title> Sehenswürdigkeiten USA </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <p>
    <div class="topNav">
      <ul>
        <a class="active" href="#home"> Home </a>
        <a href="#Impressum">Impressum</a>
        <a href="Contact"> Contact</a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </p>
  <h1>Es gibt viele schöne Sehenswürdigkeiten in den USA</h1>
</head>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `ul` can only have `li` as direct children/

Comment: Also there is no need to wrap your `div` in a `p` tag.

Comment: @Paulie_D That, and there's no body tag - that content is all inside the `<head>`.

Comment: You also have a typo in your css: tobnav instead of topnav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go have made some corrections as well;

```css
header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
}

.header h1 {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 2;
}

.topNav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}

.topNav a {
  float: left;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topNav a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgb(29, 4, 255);
}

.topNav a.active {
  background-color: #f80000;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-size: 130%;
}

table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid rgb(7, 7, 7);
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
}

th {
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initalscale=1.0" />
  <title> Sehenswürdigkeiten USA </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="topNav">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#home"> Home </a></li>
      <li><a href="#Impressum">Impressum</a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact"> Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <h1>Es gibt viele schöne Sehenswürdigkeiten in den USA</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

1. You don't meed **P** tag around div, it does pretty much the same thing i.e. provide default width and line break attribute etc. Secondly its very bad practice P inside div yes. Div inside p not so good. It just complicates things down the line ...so removed that.
2. your css had naming convention issues ...at your were using  **topNav** in html and **tobnav** or **topnav** in css. It is case sensitive so please make sure you do use same case and spellings every where.
3. removed **margin-top** from **h1** tag there was no need really
4. SOLUTION: added **margin-bottom** to **topNav** class, **intentionally have put 200px you can adjust it to what distance you like.**

Comment: If I were to guess about the down-vote, I'd assume it's because the markup in your answer is still invalid.

Comment: @Tieson T. still feel as if i am was the one sitting exam for a school lol one just needs to compare what OP posted and what he wanted done ...I updated or per say corrected bare minimum to achieve the goal. In original OP code CSS was event being applied because of this and that. if you going to down vote do leave a comment as to why?

Comment: @Syed as Tieson said, they didn't downvote you (I did not either), but your markup is incomplete and invalid. If you are going to provide an answer, make sure it's complete - and fixes errors. Your answer doesn't do any good if it's filled with errors - whether or not you answered the OPs basic problem.

Comment: Tieson T. and @disinfor ..... Thanks you two at least you communicated. I have taken on my stubborn self to upgrade the OP code to valid html ..... still it is pinchy some one would spend 5-10 odd minutes rushing to type an answer while some one else just casually  comes along and pop down without pointing towards correction. I guess highlight of the day is finding spelling mistakes in the daily news paper. :D

Comment: @Syed I formatted your snippet to be cleaner. I also removed information that was incorrect from your #2 point. Underscores in CSS naming conventions are used all over the place, mostly for BEM style. Camel case (as in OPs code) is also acceptable, if it's consistently used.

Comment: @disinfor much appreciated. and rightly done so. Thank you for your time and effort.